# Add a dynamic watermark on all the videos in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I would like to add dynamic watermark to all the videos on wordpress. Watermark will have username and email of the users who is playing the video. to watch the video viewer must be logged in.

What is have done is this.

```
<div id="overlay-details" style="
            position: absolute;
            top: 42%;
            left: 40%;
            z-index: 9999;
            margin: 11px;
            background: #82827d;
            padding: 5px;
            color: white;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
">
    <div class="line_one">UserName : NAME </div>
    <div class="line_two">Email: EMAIL </div>
</div>
```

If you can help me to implement below requests.

1. I would like to the watermark to vanish every 25 sec and to be shown for 5 sec.

2)How can i call the Wordpress username and Email.

3)is there a way to add the above code into function section of the wordpress so when new video is added to get watermark automatically?

Comment: a watermark must be added server-sided to the video itself. If you add it through frontend (HTML, CSS, or JS)  then the user can simply disable it from the dev tools and the watermark itself will be useless.

Comment: is there a way i can do it on wordpress?

Comment: Have a look on this article: https://medium.com/@dotcom.software/adding-a-watermark-to-a-video-in-php-81ee7fabd0c It seems that is not hard to add a watermark in php.

Comment: Nope, WordPress is just a CMS to display content in the front end. It does not add watermarks to a video itself. For that you need the video, apply a watermark to it. render the video again to merge the watermark into the video as in any other way it will be removable. If you allow a user to disable a watermark simply, then there is no reason to add it unless you want to annoy the user.

Comment: If you do not know php, here is an article about wordpress plugins for watermarks: https://betterstudio.com/wordpress-plugins/best-wordpress-watermark-plugins/

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div id="overlay-details" class="video-watermark">
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>
    <div class="line_one">UserName : <?= $current_user->user_login; ?> </div>
    <div class="line_two">Email: <?= $current_user->user_email; ?> </div>
</div>
<style>
@keyframes flash {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  15% { opacity: 1; }
  20% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.video-watermark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 40%;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 11px;
  background: #82827d;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  animation: flash 15s infinite alternate;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you can you tell me where can i add this in wordpress so it can be apply on every video?

Comment: while this will work visually it is a pure frontend thing. If I download the video or image the watermark will be gone. Also, I could simply use the dev tool to disable that watermark and as such bypass the security reason for a watermark.

Comment: website wont allow the video to be downloaded. the reason for watermark is if they screen record the video to see from which account video was recorded.